# Split DNS for a VPN site without a server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, vpn, split-dns

So here's my current setup:

Home:
RV220W

Office:
RV042

I have an IPSEC VPN running fine and dandy. Everything pings. I can manually nslookup to my dns servers over the VPN just fine.

Now, despite what Cisco may claim, RV220W doesn't have a working split DNS. I'm abandoning even trying that method. It's a buggy router, but the VPN works, so I'm going to work with what I have. It's one of only Cisco routers that has Gigabit WAN, Wireless and IPSEC connectivity. The other has slower VPN performance, so I'm staying with it.

At home, I have two Windows 8 desktops that I want to add to the domain to make things easier. Let's ignore PPTP/L2TP/SSDP for now and I just want to work with IPSEC.

I don't have a server here to home to use as a DNS server with conditional forwarding or to replicate the Server 2008 R2 DNS.

I figured it's probably easier to do the split DNS on the two local machines than start killing one of my machine's resources to run a VM.

Now, all I would want is to if a DNS requests *.mydomainname.com, then query 10.0.0.1 and/or 10.0.0.6 (my work's DNS servers).

I haven't found anything in windows that'll let me do that. I came up with is write a service that will query my DNS servers for my domain's forward lookup zone and write that into windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
Theoretically, it would work.

I think looked into BIND, but to be honest, I find it far too confusing to use.

I would just want (in pseudocode):

```
if (domainsuffix == "mydomainname.com")
  return: requestedHostname from 10.0.0.1;
else
  return: default;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) for my DNS (and DHCP) server at home; configuration is very straightforward:

`server=/somedomain.local/<ip.of.your.work.dns.server>`

You can build a tiny Linux virtual machine with `dnsmasq` running on VirtualBox, leave it running all the time; you'll never notice it.

Comment: Thanks, but a VM really is a last resort at this point. I do have a Linkstation on my network that's always on so I could probably root and install dnsmasq, so I'll consider that if I can't get it work on Windows.

Comment: a VM running a proper DNS server is a "last resort" but writing some kludgey zone scraping script or rooting a Linkstation is not?

Comment: Tell me, which one uses more resources?

Comment: the latter two use more human resources... far more expensive.

Comment: Rooting took about 10 minutes. It's well documented how to root most linkstations. I took your advise and just installed dnsmasq on linux... but on my linkstation. I added the line you suggested and set my router's DHCP to point the DNS for the linkstation and it worked.

Comment: nice! love it when a plan comes together.